# In ng-options group by selected option is not appearing

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

see the image:
[image: see the image] I have issue while working with AngularJS ng-options, the already selected option is not showing even though ng-model have value, please can any one help me to resolve the issue. Here I am sharing my code HTML code and JavaScript code

HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller="skillController">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row" data-ng-if="initial" >
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Skill</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Exp In
                        years</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Exp In
                        months</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "
                            data-ng-model="choice.skill" data-ng-options="skills.Skill group by skills.Category for skills in skillsList">
                            <option value="">Select skill</option>
                            <!-- <option data-ng-options="skills.Skill group by skills.Category for skills in skillsList">{{skills.Skill}} -->
                        </select>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"
                            data-ng-model="choice.years">
                            <option value="">Select years</option>
                            <option data-ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "
                            data-ng-model="choice.months">
                            <option value="">Select months</option>
                            <option data-ng-repeat="month in months">{{month}}</option>
                        </select>

                        <button class="remove" data-ng-show="$last"
                            data-ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                        <button class="add" data-ng-show="$last"
                            data-ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <button class="addfields" data-ng-click="submit()">Save&nbsp;Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <br> <br>

        <div class="row" data-ng-if="fildset">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                <div data-ng-if="choices.length>0">

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9cc2e3">
                            <th>Skill</th>
                            <th>Exp.in Years</th>
                            <th>Exp.in Months</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tbody data-ng-repeat="set in  choices ">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ set .skill.Skill }}</td>
                                <td>{{ set .years }}</td>
                                <td>{{ set .months }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <button class="addfields" data-ng-click="editSkills()">Edit&nbsp;Skills</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
            <!--  for edit -->
        <div class="row" data-ng-if="edit">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Skill</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Exp In
                        years</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Exp In
                        months</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in  choices track by $index">
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 "
                            data-ng-model="choice.skill" data-ng-options="skills.Skill group by skills.Category for skills in skillsList">


                        </select>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"
                            data-ng-model="choice.years">
                            <option value="">Select years</option>
                            <option data-ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                        <select class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "
                            data-ng-model="choice.months">
                            <option value="">Select months</option>
                            <option data-ng-repeat="month in months">{{month}}</option>
                        </select>

                        <button class="remove" data-ng-show="$last"
                            data-ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <button class="addfields" data-ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add&nbsp;Another&nbsp;Skill</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <button class="addfields" data-ng-click="submit()">Save&nbsp;Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var skill = angular.module('skillregister', [ 'shared.serviceFactory']).controller('skillController',
        function($scope, $http, serviceFactory) {
            $scope.fildset = false;
            $scope.edit = false;
            $scope.initial = true;

            $scope.skillsList = [];//[ "C language", "C++ language", "JAVA", "J2EE","Angular Js"]


            $scope.years = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30']

            $scope.months = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']

            var request = serviceFactory.getPacket('getSkillList','GET');
            $http(request).success(function successCallback(response) {

                    $scope.skillsList = response;

                console.log($scope.skillsList);
            }).error(function(data, status) {

            });




            $scope.choices = [{'skill': '','years': '', 'months': '' }];

              $scope.addNewChoice = function() {

               // var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
                $scope.choices.push({'skill': '','years': '', 'months': '' });
              };

              $scope.removeChoice = function() {
                var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
                $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
              };

              $scope.submit = function(){

                  console.log("choices---->",$scope.choices);
                  var details = {
                          'skillset': $scope.choices
                  }

                    var request = serviceFactory.getPacket('insertSkillSet', 'POST',
                            details);
                    $http(request).success(function successCallback(response) {

                        $scope.response = response.result;

                        if ($scope.response == 'success') {
                            console.log($scope.response);

                            location.reload();

                        } else {
                            window.alert("changes update failed");
                        }

                    }).error(function(data, status) {

                    });
              }
                var request = serviceFactory.getPacket('getSkillSet','GET');
                $http(request).success(function successCallback(response) {

                    if(response!=""){
                        $scope.choices = response;
                        $scope.initial = false;
                        $scope.fildset = true;
                    }

                    console.log($scope.choices);
                }).error(function(data, status) {

                });
                $scope.editSkills = function(){
                    $scope.edit = true;
                    $scope.fildset = false;

                }   
        })
```

Comment: I will have a look today afternoon, if your question is not answered yet then

Comment: I need to know how your response from `getSkillList` looks like.

Comment: look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/fz19gmxn/ shortened version without http requests will work, so i think your request is returning something unexpected

Comment: my skillList response is coming like this                                                              [{"skill":{"Category":"Server","Skill":"Core Java},"years":"01","months":"05"},{...},{...}]

Comment: and i saw your link ,in my case also for the first time the selected value appearing ,those selected skilldata i am storing in database,next time user can able to see the data which he/she submitted and i have given edit option ,so if you click on edit the same data will come as editable fields in that case the skill is  not appearing as selected.

Comment: So, if i replace the first entry, it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/fz19gmxn/1/ ... in your case i maybe need compete access... its too complicated to rebuild this situation without requests and "finished" code

Comment: In what way you can access,so that i will make arrange

Comment: acess to webpage and ftp or you can send me a mail with zipped files

Comment: I think your ´skillList´ from server shouldn't be your ´skillList´ but your choices

Comment: try `var request = serviceFactory.getPacket('getSkillList','GET');
            $http(request).success(function successCallback(response) {

                    $scope.coices.concat(response);`

Comment: send your mail id to srinubodapati36@gmail.com so that i can share files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
$http(request).success(function successCallback(response) {

                if(response!=""){
                    $scope.choices = response;
                    $scope.initial = false;
                    $scope.fildset = true;
                }
                // angular is checking items to select in a selectbox by exact reference (===)
                // so you need to replace the skill in your choice with the item from your SkillList to ensure, that angular can find out which entry to select at start
                $scope.choices.forEach(function(choice) {
                    choice.skill = $scope.skillList.filter(function(item){return item.Skill == choice.Skill})[0]
                });

                console.log($scope.choices);
            }).error(function(data, status) {

            });
```

another tip:
I am working with cache.
I am caching each item from response and if i get an other response which will match with (class and) id from an entry in my cache, i use the item from cache.
Thas will also allow you to rename the entry once and every place where the item is shown in your view, the new name will be shown

Comment: Thanks @Markus  you  helped me lot.